# How to check if the fragment exists?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to talk to the fragment from activity, but I am not sure if the fragment is visible or no. If the fragment does not exist, I cannot even do null check as it throws exception due to the casting.

How do I check if the fragment exists?

```
PlayerFragment = (PlayerFragment) mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_container);
playerFragment.onNotificationListener.updateUI();
```

Comment: Can't you do the null check and only after that do the casting?

Comment: I tried. After casting the object does not contain needed elements.

Comment: have you add this framgent in your activity's xml file

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't cast it at first.

```
Fragment f = mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_container);
if(f != null && f instanceof PlayerFragment) {
    PlayerFragment playerFragment = (PlayerFragment) f;
    playerFragment.onNotificationListener.updateUI();
}
```

If that doesn't work post the stacktrace with the exception you are receiving.

Answer (score 12):

Casting `null` to a reference won't throw an exception, to a primitive, it will.

Use `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()` to get a reference and check if its null, if not, check the reference's `isAdded()` or `isVisible()`.

```
PlayerFragment p = (PlayerFragment) mManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_container);
if( p != null && p.isAdded()){
   p.onNotificationListener.updateUI();
}
```