# Android Firebase Notification

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications

I want to handle multiple notifications in Android Notification tray like gmail handles the notification. Multiple Notifications show in a single view but each notification is individually click able.

[image]

as show in picture multiple gmail notifications are there in single view but each one is individually clickable.
please share your answers.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: so far multiple notifications are displayed in a single view as a group. But i want to click each notification individually.

Comment: From where are you receiving those.notifications?

Comment: i am using firebase for notifications

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a custom Fragment that you launch when you get a Firebase Notification. Something like this:

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .show(new FragmentIncomingNotification())
                    .commit();
```

Then what you can do is check to see if the fragment exists by using something like: 
[How to check if the fragment exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041992/how-to-check-if-the-fragment-exists)

On subsequent notifications and if it doesn't exist then launch it using the code above otherwise you could then use the LocalBroadcastManager messaging to send a message to the fragment to add a new item to your display.